# In bio systems there is the process of the increase of a system complexity. What are detailed QM explanations for such a process?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, information

In the systems far for equilibrium, there are two main processes possible in each: (1) entropy production (EP) according to the second law of thermodynamics and (2) the increase of a system complexity (ISC) that can be seen in the biological systems. I am looking for understanding what are the QM reasons for both processes. Some scholars state that the EP process, which is related to loss of info, is due to entanglement and decoherence (e.g., Schlosshauer, M. (2007). Decoherence and the Quantum-to-Classical Transition. Berlin, Germany: Springer). But I did not find good explanations for the SCI process from the QM point of view and it relation to information. My crude understanding is that the ISC process is due to QM entanglement, coherence and superposition during particle interaction. Is it right? If it is right, what are some details of this process? What are references for explanation of the ISC process?